# WPS Office CSV Delimiter - Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, csv, wps-spreadsheet

I have been using LibreOffice for all my Spreadsheet and Wordprocessing requirements lately but am getting fed up with the performance issues, it has a massive lag and also constantly freezes.

I have decided to give WPS Office a try and instantly notice that it is a lot smoother and feels like a more professionally build office suite. That being said, it also feels a olt mre restricted in what it offers, however, luckily The office products that it does not seem to offer, I dont seem to require.

My main issue with it at the minute is CSV files. The nature of my business requires easy use of CSVs as I download CSV files from my supplier and also upload CSV files to my own website.

In WPS Office the CSV file will open, however, everything is in the same box. It does not give me the option to select the delimiter.

I have checked online and this seems to be a common error but no one seems to be able to offer a fix. 
Is there a way to easily combat this issue?

My CSV sheets use `,` as the delimiter and my supplier uses `;` so I need to be able to change between the two.

LibreOffice and Microsoft office both ask me to select the Delimiter when opening the sheet. WPS does not seem to offer this

I am using linux Mint, dont know if that makes a difference? it didnt seem to have any effects on Libreoffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open your csv file with WPS Spreadsheets

Select the `A` column -> `Data` -> `Text to Columns` -> `Next` -> Select or define your delimiter -> `Finish`

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried this after posting my question, but my problem is that you can only edit one row at a time. The CSV that I download from my supplier, displays in an odd fashion when I open it. the information from some columns get put into one cell and other columns get put into 2 cells. Causing the problem that when I then use text to columns, it works for some columns and in others, some information gets deleted. Is there any way that it can operate like most other spreadsheets and give the option to chose a delimiter when I initially open the CSV file?

Comment: sorry,  I don't see that option

Answer (score 0):

In WPS 2016 you can `Select first column` -> `Data` -> `Text to column` -> `Delimited` -> `Select your delimiter` -> `Next` -> `Finish`
[Select column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCBvo.png)
[Choose "Delimited"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi3kb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use excel instead, after downloading the CSV document, open a new Excel sheet, click on 'Data' then click on 'From Text'.

[image: STEP 1]

It takes you to a page for you to upload your CSV file. Click on import and choose the delimiter.

[image: STEP 2]

Click on the semicolon.

[image: Click on semicolon]

Then finish.

Answer (score 0):

Open a blank spreadsheet on a Google account. Then do File>import>upload and choose your csv file. With the default options that display the displayed menu, works well